# Validating Javascript Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a web page with two TextBoxFor fields that utilize Javascript autocomplete.  With one of the fields, ClientUser, the response includes an integer and a string.  The integer is then compared with another integer field on the page, ClientID, and if they match, the string is used in the autocomplete suggestions.  The other field's response, WorkmateUser, is a string list immediately usable in the autocomplete.

The controller is being hit and returning the correct total list, then the correct Url/field needing validation is chosen, but the list needing validation is undefined for the ClientUser autocomplete field needing validation.  What is the most efficient way to compare an integer field on the page with an integer returned for the autocomplete list?  Thanks in advance!

Razor:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.WorkmateUser, "Workmate To Add", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkmateUser, new { data_autocomplete_url = Url.Action("GetWorkmates"), @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClientID, "Firm To Include", "--Choose Firm--")
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClientID, StaticCache.GetClients(Model.UserID), new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClientUser, "Client To Add", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClientUser, new { data_autocomplete_url = Url.Action("GetAllClients"), @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('*[data-autocomplete-url]')
            .each(function () {
                var $url = $(this);
                $(this).autocomplete({
                    source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url"),
                    response: function (data) {
                        if ($(this).data("autocomplete-url") == "/Message/GetAllClients") {
                            var aList = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {//data.length is undefined!!!
                                if (data[i].ClientID == $("#ClientID").val()) {
                                    aList.push(data[i].FirstName);
                                }
                            }
                            return bros;
                        }
                        else {
                            return data;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @gaetanoM How do you mean?

Comment: @gaetanoM Would the $(this).data( replace the loop?  I'm fairly inexperienced, so I apologize for not entirely following.

Comment: I'm sorry. Could you try changing in your code $(this).data("autocomplete-url") == "/Message/GetAllClients" with $(this).data("autocompleteUrl") == "/Message/GetAllClients"?

Comment: @gaetanoM data.length is unfortunately still undefined after that change.

Comment: can you check: $(this).data("autocomplete-url") (the source value)? Can you log the data returned? Are there any error?....

Comment: @gaetanoM That generates "/Message/GetAllClients", which correctly identifies the field for which further validation is necessary.  Once at the for loop, the data.length is undefined and prevents the loop from starting.  Is there something else within the $(this).data("autocomplete-url") that would be beneficial?

Comment: @gaetanoM When I hover over the $(this) and check the "value", that value is whatever letter is typed into the source field $("#ClientUser") that needs autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the most elegant solution, but I ended up separating out the autocomplete call that needs validation into its own script and passing the additional variable into the controller to do validation on the back end.  The following works:

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('keyup', '#ClientUser', function () {
        var abID = $(this),
            cID = $("#ClientID").val(),
            cList = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllClients", "Message")',
            data: { term: abID.val(), clientID: cID },
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    cList.push(data[i]);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Client employeess could not be pulled.");
            }
        });
        abID.autocomplete({
            source: cList
        });
    });
</script>
```